# How to count the number of post by author in D7?

Tags: display-suite

I am using the following code in drupal 6 but now this code does not work with Drupal 7.

```
<?php
$uid=$node->uid;
$results=db_query("select COUNT(nid) AS count from node where uid=$uid");

while ($res = db_fetch_object($results)) {
print "<p>" . $node->name . " has submitted <em><strong>" . $res->count . "</strong></em>          source code / articles.</p>";
}
?>
```

My primary problem is on how to query the number of post like the sql statement above as:

`db_query("select COUNT(nid) AS count from node where uid=$uid");`

Anyone know the equivalent to this on D7?

BTW, I want to use the code in display suite module.

Answer (score 2):

The result of `db_query()` should now be iterated over directly, `db_fetch_object()` isn't part of Drupal 7.

You could also make use of the `fetchField()` method to get the result of your `COUNT` query:

```
$uid = $node->uid;
$args = array(':uid' => $uid);
$count = db_query('SELECT COUNT(nid) FROM {node} WHERE uid = :uid', $args)->fetchField();

print "<p>$node->name has submitted <em><strong>$count</strong></em> source code / articles.</p>";
```

The above example uses the preferred method of passing arguments to a database query, it's safer than including them directly in the query string.

If you did want to loop over the results (for a query with more than one row/field) you'd do it like this:

```
$result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {node}');
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $nid = $row->nid;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. However, after I tried it on display suite and even in page content type with php code filter the result is still zero.

Answer (score 2):

Or even nicer... in Drupal 7 you can also get the result like this:

```
$count = db_select('node', 'n')->fields('n', array('nid'))->condition('uid', $uid)->execute()->rowCount();
print "<p>user has submitted <em><strong>$count</strong></em> articles.</p>";
```

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't work for me. I had to change the command to this so the SELECT statement is valid: db_select('node', 'n')->fields('n', array('nid'))->condition('uid', $uid)->execute()->rowCount();